# What was the purpose of showing Private White sitting in full uniform?

Tags: plot-explanation, band-of-brothers

Watching Band of Brothers and in the first show, they're all getting ready to run Currahee, and everyone has changed except for Private White, whose still in his uniform. What was the purpose of that storywise? Seemed very confusing for someone that isn't familiar with the military

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Private White didn't change gear because he was refusing to run Currahee; in essence he was quitting which we are supposed to surmise from his failure to answer Lipton. You can read a nice synopsis of the episode [here](http://everything2.com/title/Band+of+Brothers%253A+Part+One+-+%2522Currahee%2521%2522)  or [here](http://wikiofbrothers.wikia.com/wiki/Currahee) if you missed any other details.